# python starred expression on iterators with 1 item

Tags: python

I am working with regex and I'm recieving an iterator with only one object in it. In the following example To simplify I just represent it with a variable var being a list containing only one item. I want to simply recreate that variable but istead of being a list with a single item, I want it to be the item contained within the list. I found a solution as seen below but it seems unnatural. My other attempt raises an error. What's the best way to do what I did below

```
var = [1]
_, var = None, *var
print(var) # prints 1
*var = *var # raises Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "unwrap" the element from a 1-item iterable container:

```
[var] = var
```

It will be an error condition (specifically a `ValueError` exception) in the case that the container was empty or longer than 1.